# How do I cache 'pip install' packages on CircleCI?

Tags: circleci

Is there a way to do this?

For example, I currently always install a specific version of docker-compose in the circle.yml file but I'd like this to be installed already via cache:

```
- sudo -H pip install -U docker-compose==1.3.3
```

I tried adding the following to the `circle.yml` but it doesn't work (nothing related to docker-compose was saved in the .cache/pip dir after the install):

```
 cache_directories:
    - /home/ubuntu/.cache/pip
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the help from Alexey (from Circle), got the solution:

Use a `requirements.txt` to install pip dependencies, i.e.:

```
docker-compose == 1.3.3
```

Modify the `circle.yml` file to add python as a dependency and do the pip install:

```
machine:
  python:
    version: 2.7.6

dependencies:
  pre:
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: So how does the final circle.yml looks like?

Comment: The parts I quoted should be the only addition you need to a working `circle.yml` file.  Is there some specific info you are looking for @mavarazy?  You can see a sample circle.yml here: https://circleci.com/docs/config-sample.  I don't think it would be useful for me to paste my full project yml file because there is a lot of irrelevant things in there and project specific details

Comment: Unable to get caching to work this way. Expanding the `pip install` step on the build shows that it's still downloading the packages.

Comment: According to circle ci docs: https://circleci.com/docs/language-python/#package-managers-and-dependencies as it finds a `requirements.txt` on the project root it will automatically run `pip` to install the packages. I'm using this default approach and cache works as expected and I see `Requirement already satisfied` as the command is triggered within the dependencies section. Hope that helps!